# AS3- Removing childs from stage when changing scene through a function

Tags: function, actionscript-3, timer, removechild, scene

I'm currently creating a game in which a player controls a spaceship which shoots enemy ships. I've added a timer to the scene so that after 60 seconds the movie clip of the 'mother ship' explodes and disappears. However when this happens I want to move to a different scene as a 'level complete' scene, but once I change scenes it carries the game over with me and sort of well.. continues. You can still see the enemies flying around and this is not what I want. I've attempted (poorly I imagine) this problem and just want to know how I would remove these function from running as the RemoveEventListener's I have added are not doing the job. To clarify, I'd like to know how to remove all childs/ eventlisteners and end all functions for when I go to the next scene. (It's the leveltimer function Im having difficulties with) Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

A LOT is missing from this code. Let's break down all your functions to see what is going on and why things aren't working.

When your timer runs out, you've tried to remove two of the listeners like this:

```
removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, addbEnemy);
removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onclick);
```

For the first one, I can't figure out why this function even exists. All it does is add the same `Benemy` object to the stage over and over again each frame, in the exact same position. You should figure out why this function exists, and if it's even necessary.

As for the second one, `onclick` does not take an ENTER_FRAME event. It takes a CLICK event. So you need to change it to this in order to remove click events: `stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onclick);`

Great, now you can no longer click to add bullets. But what about everything else? Well you haven't removed any listeners that control the other objects yet. You can start by stopping all your running timers.

```
tm.stop();
myTimer.stop();
tm.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onstart);
myTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, levelTimer);
```

Okay, now the timers are stopped, so no new enemies should spawn, and the ship will not explode after every 60 seconds.
What next? The hero is still moving around, so remove the ENTER_FRAME event that controls the hero: `removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onenter);`

The last thing is all the enemies on the screen.

Unfortunately, I don't even see the code that handles enemy movement in the code you posted. I assume their movement is handled within the `enemy` class, so you need to add a stop function to that class and then call it on each enemy.

Unfortunately, all your enemies are added to the stage within the local scope of the `onstart()` function, so you've lost access to them. There are two ways to fix this:

1. Do a loop over all children on the stage and check if each is an enemy and if so, call the stop function you created.
2. Within the `onstart()` function, add each enemy into an array to store access to it. Then, in the `levelTimer()` function, loop over each array element and call the stop function.

Comment: @NicholasAndrewThompson I agree, the Array is the better way to do it. Good luck